# Getting exception "Cannot access a disposed context instance." during db transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting the following exception while updating a record from `Slot` model. The exception is:

```
"Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a
 context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use 
the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 
'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using 
dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of 
disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'ApplicationDbContext'."
```

and my method from the repositories are:

```
public async Task<Response> AddCourseToSlot(Guid slotId, Guid courseId)
{
    try
    {
        var slot = await _context.Slots.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == slotId);

        if (slot == null)
        {
            return new Response
            {
                message = "Sorry, this slot does not exist.",
                status = "error",
                flag = 0
            };
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slot.CourseIds) && slot.CourseIds.Split(',').Contains(courseId.ToString()))
        {
            return new Response
            {
                message = "Sorry, this course has already been added.",
                status = "error",
                flag = 0
            };
        }

        var course = await _context.Courses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == courseId);

        if (course == null)
        {
            return new Response
            {
                message = "Sorry, this course does not exist.",
                status = "error",
                flag = 0
            };
        }

        if (CountHours(course.Id))
        {
            return new Response
            {
                message = "Sorry, the course has exceeded its credit hours limit.",
                status = "error",
                flag = 0
            };
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slot.TeacherIds) && slot.TeacherIds.Split(',').Contains(course.TeacherId.ToString()))
        {
            return new Response
            {
                message = "Sorry, the teacher already has a course in this slot.",
                status = "error",
                flag = 0
            };
        }
        
        slot.CourseIds += $",{course.Id}";
        slot.TeacherIds += $",{course.TeacherId}";
        _context.Slots.Update(slot);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new Response
        {
            message = "The course has been successfully added to this slot.",
            status = "success",
            flag = 1
        };
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new Response
        {
            message = ex.ToString(),
            status = "error",
            flag = 0
        };
    }
    
}
```

```
private bool CountHours(Guid courseId)
{
    var ids = _context.Slots.Where(x => x.CourseIds != null).Select(x => x.CourseIds).ToList();
        
    if(ids != null)
    {
        List<Guid> courseIds = ids
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(guid => Guid.Parse(guid.Trim()))
        .ToList();

        int count = courseIds.Count(id => id == courseId);

        return count >= 3;
    }   

    return false;
}
```

**I tried to run it on debug mode and found the exception occurs while trying to save changes to the database**. But not able to identify which causes the `dbcontext` disposal. So can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you awaiting `AddCourseToSlot`? Are you awaiting what calls `AddCourseToSlot`? Are you awaiting what calls that? Do you have a chain of awaits all the way up to the async web request?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Thanks. Yes, I forgot to `await` while calling this interface method call from the controller.

Comment: @Jackdaw Thank you for your response. I made a very silly mistake to not `await` the `AddCourseToSlot` while calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that I forgot to `await` while calling this method from the controller. So why has it not worked before? It is, If you forgot to await the asynchronous method call while invoking it from the controller, it would result in the method executing synchronously instead of asynchronously. This can cause blocking of the main thread, especially if the method performs time-consuming operations such as querying the database.